# jQuery - option buttons reset cancelled

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have a single checkbox that indicates that a user would like dinner. Under this checkbox are several radio buttons from which the user can select his/her dinner option. I am looking for two things to happen...

1) Whenever the user "checks" that they would like dinner I have a default dinner choice option selected. When the user "un-checks" the dinner option I want all the dinner choices deselected. All this is working fine until I try and add an additional jQuery option.

2) If the user selects a dinner option I would like the checkbox that indicates that the user wants dinner to be checked. This last option seems to negate the first.

I have created a jsfiddle.net example located here ... http://jsfiddle.net/ScEw2/1/

I have also pasted the code here for example ...

**HTML**

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="IsHavingDinner" name="Dinner" /> Do you want dinner?</p>
<hr />
<input type="radio" id="DinnerChoiceChicken" name="DinnerChoice" value="Chicken"> Chicken<br/>
<input type="radio" id="DinnerChoiceFish" name="DinnerChoice" value="Fish"> Fish<br/>
<input type="radio" id="DinnerChoiceSteak" name="DinnerChoice" value="Steak"> Steak<br/>
<input type="radio" id="DinnerChoiceVegan" name="DinnerChoice" value="Vegan"> Vegan<br/>
```

**jQuery code**

```
// Select default dinner option otherwise deselect all options
$('#IsHavingDinner').click(function(event) {
    if ($('#IsHavingDinner').attr('checked')) {
        // Select Dinner Choice Chicken by default
        $('#DinnerChoiceChicken').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        // Deselect all Dinner Choices
        $('input[name="DinnerChoice"]').attr('checked', false);
    }
})

// If a dinner choice is selected, make sure the checkbox
// indicating they want dinner is selected
$('[name="DinnerChoice"]').click(function(event) {
    $('#IsHavingDinner').attr('checked', 'checked');
})
```

I cannot determine why the dinner options are not deselected if the user deselect dinner. Is one event cancelling the other? Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking for [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/4Vf49/)?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks Shef! Is there a way to give you credit?

Comment: Great, I am posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Select default dinner option otherwise deselect all options
// Listen for a change event on the having dinner checkbox
$('#IsHavingDinner').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){ // if checked
        $('#DinnerChoiceChicken').prop('checked', true); // check a default dinner choice
    } else {
        $('input[name="DinnerChoice"]').prop('checked', false); // otherwise, uncheck all
    }
});

// If a dinner choice is selected, make sure the checkbox 
// indicating they want dinner is selected
$('input[name="DinnerChoice"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){ // if checked
        $('#IsHavingDinner').prop('checked', true); // check having dinner
    }
});
```

Comment: Giving answer to Shef as he posted it first. However, answer by @rfausak is great also.

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery's [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of `click()`. `click()` is executed before the checkbox changes.

```
$('#IsHavingDinner').change(function(event) { ..
```

Also use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()` in JQuery 1.6+.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the click() event is executing before the change. That really helps!